# Spring init method with parameters issue

Tags: java, spring, servlets, dependency-injection

so I'm learning spring dependency injection and have come around with an issue.I've two classes...one is the *Run* class and the other is *Builders* class.The *Builders* class has a **static method abc** that accepts **multiple parameters** and returns an object of type *Run*.
It looks something like this:

```
public class Run{
    private final Check check;

    public Run(Check check){
        this.check = check;

    }
    public Check getCheck() {
        return check;
    }
}

public class Builders {
    public static Run abc(multiple arguments) {
        Check check = ProxyImplClass.createCheck(multiple arguments);
        return new Run(check);
    }
}
```

I need to call the below mentioned statement only once on application startup.

**Run run = Builders.abc (....accepts multiple parameters....);**

How do I do that using the spring xml?If some changes are required in the class files, then please mention that too as I'm quite new to this Spring framework.

Note:....multiple parameters inside the abc method only signifies that the method takes multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `factory-method` attribute of `<bean>`. To use the `static` factory method of a different class, use the `class` attribute to specify the class containing the method.

Whatever arguments you want to pass to the method goes in `<constructor-arg>` tag:

```
<bean id="run" class="pkg.Builders" factory-method="abc">
    <constructor-arg type="..." value="...">
    <constructor-arg type="..." value="...">
</bean>
```

Comment: Hey Rohit....thanks for your precious time....Just wanted to know that whether the same will get called upon application startup?

Comment: @Sandy Yes. If lazy-init is not set to true.